# Promise & Recursion, how to handle found item without a callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, recursion, promise

I have a folder hierarchy on the server. I would like to loop over this hierarchy asynchronously and recursively, and when a file is found, call a custom method.

For now, my code looks like this:

```
searchFile(root, handleFile);

// loop over all folders recursively, then handle files
function searchFile(item, callbackWhenFile) {
    if (itIsFolder(item)) {
        $http.get("api.call.com/children/" + item.id)
                .then(function (children) {
                    angular.forEach(children,
                        function (child) {
                            searchFile(child, callbackWhenFile);
                        });
                });
    }
    else {
        // this is not a folder, so this is a file
        callbackWhenFile(item);
    }
}
```

The fact that the callback is used instead of promises is not a good thing.

But I tried to find a way to make it work with promises with no chance.

In an ideal solution, I would like to do something like:

```
searchFile(root).then(function (file) {
     handleFile(file)
});
```

I looked at $q.all, $q.when, but nothing seems to fit to this case. The fact that we don't know the number of files we are going to have make the problem difficult.

Anyone have an idea how to solve that problem?

**Edit Answer**

[Promises are not the way to go.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32481044/128662)

With RxJS and the observable objects, this can be written as:

```
getFileStream(root).subscribe(function (file) {
    handleFile(file);
});

function getFileStream(root) {
    var source = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        observeFiles(observer, root);
    });
    return source;
}

function observeFiles(observer, item) {
    if (itIsFolder(item)) {
        $http.get("api.call.com/children/" + item.id)
                .then(function (children) {
                    angular.forEach(children,
                        function (child) {
                            searchFile(observer, child);
                        });
                });
    }
    else {
        observer.onNext(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Better rewrite server method. Make 999 requests to search single file? How that may work in real life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Promise can only resolve to a single value. That value can be an object, or an array but in the end, it's a single value - not a stream.

Your "ideal solution" is defined as if it does generate a stream and that's not possible.

You can:

1. Leave your code as it is. Your callback is being called asynchronously, and does so as soon as there is a file to process.
2. Change your recursion to assemble a single value. Either a flat array / map (object...) of files. That value can then be processed SYNCHRONOUSLY inside the next function (`.then(processArray)`).
3. Use a streaming library like [BaconJS](https://baconjs.github.io/) or [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS).

Answer (score -1):

The following code should do the trick:

```
searchFile(root).then(function (files) {
     function (files) {
         angular.forEach(files,
                         function (file) {
                             handleFile(file);
                         });
     });
});

// loop over all folders recursively, then handle files
function searchFile(item) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var files = [];
    if (itIsFolder(item)) {
        $http.get("api.call.com/children/" + item.id)
                .then(function (children) {
                    angular.forEach(children,
                        function (child) {
                            searchFile(child).then(
                               function (files) {
                                   angular.forEach(files,
                                   function (file) {
                                       files.add(file);
                                   });
                               });
                        });

                        deferred.resolve(files);
                });
    }
    else {
        files.add(item);
        deferred.resolve(files);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Hi @piyuj, thank you for your answer. I've tried something similar, but the promise will be resolve on the first file found, so the files array will contains only one item. Further found files will not be treated.

Comment: If you run search over a file it will only find a file.
But if you run it on a folder the recursion will create as many promises as searchFile calls you do. and resolve it on the then function of that block

 `searchFile(child).then(
                               function (files) {
                                   angular.forEach(files,
                                   function (file) {
                                       files.add(file);
                                   });
                               });`

Comment: @piyuj: Exactly. Only that that block does resolve with the result of the current `child` file/directory, and does not wait for all filepaths. Don't employ the deferred antipattern, use  `$q.all` instead.

Comment: May be i'm not understandig what you say. But the deferred object of the first child is not the same as the one on the first call.

Offcourse if the root is a file it will finish on the first child, but that's because this is the only child!